# Should I call removeFromSuperview or is release just fine?

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-sdk-3.0, uikit

I add a subview using addSubview method in a subclass of UITableViewCell when creating it.

Then, when I no longer need the view I released it in my dealloc method.
My question is what is the best way to release the view?

Is `[myView release]` enough or should I call:

```
[myView removeFromSuperview];
[myView release];
```

or just `[myView removeFromSuperview]`;

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Simple rule: If you retained it, you have to release it.

I am assume you are saying you don't want the view on screen anymore. Than you have to call `removeFromSuperView` otherwise the superview still retain the view and release it will just transfer the ownership to the superview.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you created the view.  You should make sure that you don't own the subview when you pass it in.

I'm going to go the generic route here.

```
UIView * mySubview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[superView addSubview:mySubview];
[mySubview release];
```

You now have your subview where you want it, but the superView owns it.
If your superView is in a view hierarchy and you don't own it yourself, then when your superView is taken out of the view hierarchy so will its subview and they will be released by their respective owners.